# Warning: Undefined variable $admin

Tags: plugins, php

I'm running a wordpress plugin and continue to receive errors like:

> Undefined variable $admin in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-database\vragen_plugin.php on line 791

This was my code:

```
    // If ur an admin, you have access to the following page
    if($admin == '1'){
// When going to /Stel-vraag?createquestion=...
        if (isset($_POST['createquestion'])) {
            $short_question = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'short_question', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
            $long_question = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'long_question', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
            if (!isset($_POST['comment'])) { $comment = 'Nee';} else { $comment = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); }
            $uniq_name = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,10);
```

Comment: So where did you define $admin?  It's not defined, so the error happens.

 Perhaps you meant to use is_admin() ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling that when you say:

```
if($admin == '1'){
```

PHP has no idea what you are talking about. There is no $admin so it cannot ever equal 1.

As Rick Hellewell mentioned in the comments, you might actually want [is_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) which is a function that returns a boolean (true or false).

It is quite likely the code you actually want would be like this:

```
// If ur an admin, you have access to the following page
if( is_user_admin() ){
// When going ...[snip]...
```

**Edit**: *I originally suggested `is_admin()` which I was reminded checks the page is loaded in the admin area. I should have said `is_user_admin()`*

Comment: Please be aware that is_admin DOESN'T return if the user is an admin or not, but instead returns true if you are viewing a page within the "admin" (Backend) section of Wordpress at the moment this function is run...

Comment: Ah, yeah. You are right.  HU is Sebastian. I shall update my answer.

Comment: This is still not what you want ;) is_user_admin returns true if you are viewing the user admin screen in the backend, i.e. /wp-admin/user/ . If you want to know if the current user is in the admin role, you should use `current_user_can('administrator')` if you want to target the administrator role specifically, or `current_user_can('manage_options')` if you want to target users that have administrative rights...